# projectFirestore not giving back document collection in an async function in Vue?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to return user collection from Firebase/Firestore but the code I have does not return anything when I check it in the console. Can you please help me, I am new to Vue? I am trying to find the user which has the same display name as the one currently logged in but I am stuck.

```
<template>
  <p>Process Payroll</p>
  <h1>{{ user.displayName }} </h1>
  <h1>{{ docs }} </h1>
</template>

<script>
import  getUser  from '@/composables/getUser'
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { projectFirestore } from '../firebase/config'

export default {
    setup(){
        const { user } = getUser()
        const lastName = ref('')
        const firstName = ref('')
        const docs = ref('')
        
        const returnUser = async () => {
                const res = await projectFirestore.collection('users').get()
                if (!error.value) {
                    console.log(res.docs)
                    const doc = res.docs.filter((user1) =>{
                        if (user1.displayName == user.displayName){
                            return user.lastName
                        }
                    })
                    docs.value = doc
            }
        }

        return {user, docs, returnUser }
    }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Comment: Can you share what `getUser()` looks like ?

Comment: Firstly, this condition needs to be changed. `if (user.displayName == user.displayName){
                            return user.lastName
                        }`. That's just going to be true for all the users in the array. Perhaps, you could renamed the variable passed to filter function to `userObj`. Secondly, why don't you just the particular user that is required, instead of getting the entire collection and then filtering it out at client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly**, the condition that you have applied on the `filter` function needs to be changed so that the variables are not mixed up. Currently, you were comparing the element's `displayName` with itself which will always be true.

**Secondly**, you can query the document that's required from the collection with simple query. More information can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries).

Also, before jumping to the next conclusion, check the response that is returned from `firestore`. The `get()` method from `firestore` returns you a `querySnapshot` so there's no need to call `res.docs`. You will get your documents directly in `res` which will be an array. Just iterate over it to get a single document, whose properties can then be easily accessed using `.data()` method

###### Solution

```vue
<template>
  <p>Process Payroll</p>
  <h1>{{ user.displayName }} </h1>
  <h1>{{ docs }} </h1>
</template>

import getUser from "@/composables/getUser";
import { ref } from "vue";
import { projectFirestore } from "../firebase/config";

export default {
  setup() {
    const { user } = getUser();
    const lastName = ref("");
    const firstName = ref("");
    const docs = ref([]);

    const returnUser = async () => {
      const res = await projectFirestore
        .collection("users")
        .where("displayName", "==", user.displayName)
        .get();
      if (!error.value) {
        // check your response here.
        console.log(res);
        const doc = res.filter((userObj) => {
          if (user.displayName === userObj.data().displayName) {
            return user.lastName;
          }
        });
        docs.value = doc;
      }
    };

     onMounted(returnUser)

    return { user, docs, returnUser };
  },
};
```

Comment: It's still not firing the projectFirestore method and displaying nothing in the console.log(res). Thank you for helping out!

Comment: Can you check your browser `console`, for errors? There must be some initialization error or something.

Comment: Check this thread to know how to instantiate the `firestore` SDK. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#web-version-8_2

Comment: I have correctly set up firestore and there are no errors in the console. When I remove the async function, I am able to log the documents in the console using the following: const res = projectFirestore.collection('users')

Comment: gotcha. I just realized that we defined the function, but didn't really call it. We need to call the `returnUser` function in the `onMounted` hook. Should work fine now. I've updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Can you also have a look at a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69324827/user-displayname-not-accessible-inside-the-script-but-available-in-template-in-v