# User.displayName not accessible inside the script but available in template in VueJs?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a Current User composable that I am importing in my function but it returns undefined when I try to access any of the properties of the user object. Can you please help me, I am new to Vue?

Here is my template in which I am invoking the user's properties.

```js
<template>
  <p>Process Payroll</p>
  <h1>{{ user.displayName }} </h1>
  <h1>{{ docs }} </h1>
</template>

<script>
import getUser from '@/composables/getUser'
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import { projectFirestore, projectAuth } from '@/firebase/config'
import { useRouter, useRoute } from 'vue-router'

export default {
    setup() {
    const { user } = getUser();
    const lastName = ref("");
    const firstName = ref("");
    const docs = ref([]);

    const returnUser = async () => {
      const res = await projectFirestore
        .collection("users")
        .where("displayName", "==", user.displayName)
        .get();
      if (!error.value) {
        // check your response here.
        console.log(res);
        const doc = res.filter((userObj) => {
          if (user.displayName === userObj.data().displayName) {
            return user.lastName;
          }
        });
        docs.value = doc;
      }
    };

        onMounted(returnUser)

    return { user, docs, returnUser};
  },
}
</script>
```

User.displayName is undefined in my returnUser function but is available to be displayed in the template on the top. How can I access the user.displayName property in my returnUser function?

Composable:

```js
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { projectAuth } from '../firebase/config'

// refs
const user = ref(projectAuth.currentUser)

// auth changes
projectAuth.onAuthStateChanged(_user => {
  console.log('User state change. Current user is:', _user)
  user.value = _user
});

const getUser = () => {
  return { user } 
}

export default getUser
```

Comment: Seems like you might be calling `returnUser` before the `projectAuth` callback updates the user. One solution would be to use a watch like `watch(()=>user, () => returnUser())`. If the component you're working on has a parent then another option would be to get the user in the parent component and use a `v-if="user"` on this component and pass the user to the component as a prop so that it would get created only when the user is available and not before.

Comment: Do you suggest that I include it like this because that's not working either: onMounted(watch(()=>user, () => returnUser())) @InvisibleGorilla

Comment: Use the watch directly inside `setup()` not inside `onMounted`. So in the setup anytime after `const { user } = getUser();` use `watch(()=>user, () => returnUser())`.

Comment: I get a reference error on doing so "ReferenceError: error is not defined". How can I proceed forward in launching a request from firebase for the content. Right now I am seeing nothing happening. All I wanted to do was display last name and first name from firebase by referencing the current user's displayName. Is there an easier way to retrieve the last name and first name from the database or any ideas on how to go about getting the last name and first name differently? I store last name and first name with display name upon signing up.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem is that the `returnUser` will be called by `vue` regardless of the `auth` state of the current user. The auth state is changed after a split second or so by firebase, but by that time, you code inside `returnUser` has already executed. Naturally giving you `undefined` inside the `script` tag. But, as this property is reactive, it will always change when the auth state changes hence making the user details available in the template.

Solution is to just setup a watcher for the `user` property to call the `returnUser` function whenever the user's auth state changes. Rest of the code in composable can remain as is, because it's working correctly as you're able to access the user object in `template` tag.

```vue
<template>
  <p>Process Payroll</p>
  <h1>{{ user.displayName }} </h1>
  <h1>{{ docs }} </h1>
</template>

<script>
import getUser from '@/composables/getUser'
import { ref, onMounted, watch } from 'vue'
import { projectFirestore, projectAuth } from '@/firebase/config'
import { useRouter, useRoute } from 'vue-router'

export default {
    setup() {
    const { user } = getUser();
    const lastName = ref("");
    const firstName = ref("");
    const docs = ref([]);

    const returnUser = async () => {
      const res = await projectFirestore
        .collection("users")
        .where("displayName", "==", user.displayName)
        .get();
      if (!error.value) {
        const doc = res.filter((userObj) => {
          if (user.displayName === userObj.data().displayName) {
            return user.lastName;
          }
        });
        docs.value = doc;
      }
    };

    onMounted(returnUser);
    watch(user, returnUser);

    return { user, docs, returnUser};
  },
}
</script>
```

**EDIT:** I just forgot to import the `watch` method from vue previously. Updated my answer to do just that.

**@BilalHussain** I would also say first try my answer above. Now, coming to your question on a better approach to get the firstName & lastName, I could explain you what I've implemented for one of my projects. So I have used `firebase auth` for authentication & signup process. When a user registers with `firebase`, you get a [uid](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#uid) for user that doesn't change. So I would store all the user data in a collection against the `uid` as a document id.

###### Example:

| Collection | Doc | Document data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| users | xasdfoxkawe4s7sa4fa55w525asdfalsuw | { first: "John", lastName: "Doe" } |
|  | asiu82kskadla1s85sdfklsuspalsjdjd | { first: "Jack", lastName: "Sparrow" } |

When a user logs in, in the front end I always have the `uid`, so I can just query that particular document and get the data instead searching the entire collection by using the following syntax:

```js
const currentUser = await firebase.auth().currentUser;
const user = await firestore.collection("users").doc(currentUser.uid).get();
console.log(user.data())
```

So I believe, you could use a similar approach of creating a document against a unique hash in `firestore`. So when the user logs in, you have the hash and you can query it directly from firestore. Hope this helps!

###### References:

- [Querying data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)
- [Managing users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users)